# Is money received for donating blood supposed to be listed on income taxes?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

My question pertains to law in the United States.

In the United States, when people donate blood plasma, they are sometimes given money. For example $50.00, to spend 4 hours donating 880ml of blood plasma.

Legally speaking, is this income supposed to be reported to the United States Internal Revenue Service?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous and conflicting Google results, ranging from people saying giving plasma is a "donation" and as such can't be taxed because it's from your own body (and sometimes because you're being paid in a gift card), all the way to accounting firms saying the money is earned income and must be declared as miscellaneous income on tax returns if you earn more than $600/year, and even if you don't get a 1099 from the plasma collecting company.

It's pretty easy to see that donating plasma or blood can be seen as gross income, which is

> "Except as otherwise provided in this subtitle, gross income means all
> income from whatever source derived,...
> [26 U.S. Code § 61 - Gross income defined | Legal Information Institute Cornell](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61).

It's up to you if you wanted to fight the IRS over it.

Comment: There is no minimum, $600 or other, for declar[ing] miscellaneous income, although there is a minimum of $400 in most cases to be liable for _self-employment_ tax -- which only applies here if growing(?) and selling blood is a 'trade or business' under 162 as referenced by 1402, which I doubt. But if you had no other income, or sufficiently little to be under the filing threshold, and are not in a few special situations, you don't have to declare/report anything -- unless you file voluntarily to get a refund of withholding/estimated or credit(s).